# Secure storing a secret on Tizen Web App

Tags: security, local-storage, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

Which is the most secure way to secure store a secret on a Tizen Web App?

As far as I know, the only supported API to store something is `LocalStorage`.

```
// to store a value
window.localStorage.setItem( 'secret', item_value);

// to retrieve a value
item_value = window.localStorage.getItem( 'secret' );
```

We already know that in the upcoming SDK wearable 3.0.0 there will be a keychain mechanism already available in mobile SDK.

Waiting for the 3.0.0, is the LocalStorage a "safe" place to store a secret?
Is the LocalStorage inspectable via console or file system (Even without enabling the Debug mode)?

Comment: Did you try SharedPreference of Tizen?

Comment: How a SharedPreference could be secure?

Answer (score 1):

Tizen localStorage is noting but HTML5 Web Storage implementation.

[Webstorage API](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/)

[W3Shools WebStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

This [post on Tizen Developers Forum](https://developer.tizen.org/forums/web-application-development/secure-local-storage-how?langswitch=en&langredirect=1) suggests encryption/decryption.

Anyways, Searching the web you would mostly find 'strict negative' response on storing password/credential, sensitive data using Web localStorage. So, My opinion is also '**not secure**' based on:

[Can local storage ever be considered secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280390/can-local-storage-ever-be-considered-secure)

[HTML5 localStorage security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718349/html5-localstorage-security)

[Storing Credentials in Local Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859972/storing-credentials-in-local-storage)

[How secure is localstorage?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74155/how-secure-is-localstorage)

You can inspect localStorage data using Web Debbuger:

[image]

Accessing file from device's file explorer is not possible. (Except in the case of emulators and rooted devices)