# Javascript - What is the recommended/secure way to read/write settings for static web pages stored on a user's computer?

Tags: javascript, filesystems, read-write

**Background:**
I'm a tech writer at our company. I dabble in Javascript from time to time, and I consider my js skill level to be maybe advanced beginner/early intermediate.

Anyway, we have Help content created by Adobe's RoboHelp (version 2017). The Help content is static HTML5 .htm pages. The Help gets installed into a folder as a bunch of static .htm pages on our users' computers when they install our product.  The users open our .htm pages in their browser via the file:// protocol.

**Our Goal:**
On our first intro page of our Help, we're planning on showing a "What's New" .htm file inside of an iframe, but we only want to show it the first time a user accesses the documentation.

**What I Know and Have Tried:**
I know on a real web server, I'd probably just use cookies to control this. But on a local computer, cookies aren't persistent, and after the session closes, the local cookie storage gets deleted.

I know that Javascript accessing the file system unfettered is a security no no and isn't possible.

I've looked into the FileSystem API but the things I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744155/writing-file-to-desktop-using-html5-filesystem-api) indicate that it is dead and not in the standard going forward.

**My Question:**
Is there some other way in Javascript to have limited trusted access to a single settings file etc for this kind of thing? If so, what is the best / recommended way that keeps the user's computer secure but allows us to store and modify settings in a limited fashion so the user has the best experience?

Note that many of these users probably won't have access to the Internet at all, since their computers will be on a factory floor, so a solution that doesn't require talking back to the Internet is ideal.

I assume most of our users log onto their computers with a standard (non-admin) level login. How many users on the same computer will vary, and I don't have that info, though I think it's likely there will be different shifts that use the same computer.

I'm planning on just storing something simple, like boolean values (ie True/False for if this is the first time they've seen the What's New page etc).

Comment: The users open those `.htm` files in their browser via the `file://` protocol?

Comment: That's correct. @KiwiKilian I'll update my post.

Answer (score 0):

Some questions:

- Does a user login? What sort of information is planned on being stored?
- How many users will be using the same computer?
- It's not strictly secure. I wouldn't store any passwords, and personally identifiable info in localStorage, however there are some caveats ( [Storing Credentials in Local Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859972/storing-credentials-in-local-storage) ), https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/152763/html5-localstorage-and-encrypted-sensitive-data ( however if it's on a computer not connected to the internet, then maybe something simple with encryption, might be ... okay )

Might have a look at `localStorage`.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44358718/2026508
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Thanks for responding @jmunsch. I'll take a look at those links. I assume most of our users log onto their computers with a standard (non-admin) level login. How many users on the same computer will vary and I don't have that info, though I think it's likely there will be different shifts that use the same computer. I'm planning on just storing something simple like boolean values. True/False for if this is the first time they've seen the What's New Page etc. I'll update my post.